# python re: parse time

Tags: python, regex

Could you please assist: I need to find all raws that contain "45m3s UP" for example. 
My option (does not work):

```
"\d{,3}\w{1}\d{,3}\w UP"
```

What is wrong ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show us the code, input, output and requested output.

Comment: You don't need to specify one occurrence like that.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me (prints `MATCH`):

```
import re

pat = "\d{,3}\w{1}\d{,3}\w UP"
line = "45m3s UP"
if re.match(pat, line):
    print "MATCH"
else:
    print "NO MATCH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your range operator syntax `{,3}` is incorrect and `\w{1}` is redundant. The following should fix it.

```
r"\d+m\d+s UP"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is seems like you want a minute and second format, try simplifying your code:

```
for i in re.findall(r'\d+m\d+s UP', string):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all a lot!!!

works fine expression: '\d+m\d+s UP'.
As for me it looks better than "\d{,3}\w{1}\d{,3}\w" :)

HUGE Thank you!